# Not work tad <use> with data:image/svg+xml,<svg

Tags: css, svg

I want insert .svg in my .htm page. But 'use' not work in 'svg'. How make it?

```
background:url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='180' height='118' 
fill='white'><path d='M90,14 143,108H37z' stroke-width='11' 
stroke='red'/><g id='cr'><path d='M70,68 73,59H90L93,68' stroke-width='2' 
stroke='black'/><path d='M67,70H93V74H67M71,74V81M92,74V81' stroke-
width='5' stroke='black'/></g><use x='13' y='8' xlink:href='#cr'/><use 
x='26' y='16' xlink:href='#cr'/></svg>")
```

Comment: # characters are reserved in urls for the start of a fragment identifier, they must be encoded as %23

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How use fill='#fff' color instead fill='white'?

Comment: %23fff as I indicated already

Comment: 4 Robert Longson. %23fff = 6 chars, white = 5 chars, +1 char, not good :) . If color code have 6 chars then good, -1 char. Example: #1589FF=dodgerblue=%231589FF.

Answer (score 0):

There is no wrong with "use" tag here.

For some reason the URL is unable to read that SVG.

There is an alternate way, which is readable and maintainable.

Take out your SVG from URL and create a separate SVG file... for ex: test.svg

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='180' height='118' fill='white'>

<path d='M90,14 143,108H37z' stroke-width='11' stroke='red'/>

<g id='cr'>
<path d='M70,68 73,59H90L93,68' stroke-width='2' stroke='black'/>
<path d='M67,70H93V74H67M71,74V81M92,74V81' stroke-width='5' stroke='black'/>
</g>

<use x='13' y='8' xlink:href='#cr'/>
<use x='26' y='16' xlink:href='#cr'/>

</svg>
```

And  in your CSS. Call it simply, the SVG file name in URL as shown below test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
    background: url("test1.svg") no-repeat fixed center; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This way of doing helps you in

1. easy maintenance
2. reusable
3. readability

Comment: Thank. No. Its method add +1 request for page.